# Python reverse listener using threading

Tags: python, multithreading, reverse-shell

I'm working on a project that requires me to make a Python reverse listener that can send commands to a client that connects to my server, below is my server code and i am stuck on how to get multiple connections from more than just one client at the same time.

thank you

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3

import socket
import sys
import time
import threading
from queue import Queue

NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 2
JOB_NUMBER = [1, 2]
queue = Queue)
all_connections = []
all_addresses = []

# create socket
def socket_create():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        host = '0.0.0.0'
        port = 5555
        s = socket.socket()
    except socket.error as msg:
        print("Socket creation error: " + str(msg))

# bind socket to port and wait for connection from client
def socket_bind():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        print("Binding socket to port: " + str(port))
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.bind((host, port))
        s.listen(5)
    except socket.error as msg:
        print("Socket binding error: " + str(msg))
        time.sleep(5)
        socket_bind()

# accept connections from multiple clients and save to list
def accept_connections():
    for c in all_connections:
        c.close()
    del all_connections[:]
    del all_addresses[:]
    while 1:
        try:
            conn, address = s.accept()
            conn.setblocking(1)
            all_connections.append(conn)
            all_addresses.append(address)
            print("\nConnection has been established: " + address[0])
        except:
            print("Error accepting connections")

# interactive prompt
def start_luka():
    while True:
        cmd = input('luka> ')
        if cmd == 'list':
            list_connections()
        elif 'select' in cmd:
            conn = get_target(cmd)
            if conn is not None:
                send_target_commands(conn)
            else:
                print("Command not recognized")

# displays all current connections
def list_connections():
    results = ''
    for i, conn in enumerate(all_connections):
        try:
            conn.send(str.encode(' '))
            conn.recv(20480)
        except:
            del all_connections[i]
            del all_addresses[i]
            continue
        results += str(i) + '   ' + str(all_addresses[i][0]) + '   ' + str(all_addresses[i][1]) + '\n'
    print('------ Clients -----' + '\n' + results)

def main():
    socket_create()
    socket_bind()
    start_luka()
    list_connections()
    accept_connections()
main()
```

when i run this code it doesn't say the connection is established and it doesn't add the connection to the list i created.
and lastly i'm trying to make all of this automated, as in, the second a client connects to my server listener, these commands will automatically run (ls, pwd, IP a...ect) and a file would be created to store all the data so i can check it out later. not sure where to start on that.
thanks for helping